# Duration of an MP3/wav audio file

Tags: delphi, audio, mp3

How do you get the duration (in minutes and seconds) of an MP3/wav audio file in Delphi ?

Comment: What API are you using to play the MP3 file?  TMediaPlayer?

Comment: no, I'm not playing the file, I just need the information from the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can calculate the duration by dividing the size of the file by the bit rate. You can get the bit rate from one of the frame headers. Of course, this won't work for variable rate MP3s, where you can have a different rate for each frame.

Using the [Header Layout](https://www.datavoyage.com/mpgscript/mpeghdr.htm) (it's just four bytes):

1. Open the MP3 in a stream
2. Find the beginning of the first frame header by reading until you
   find the sync header, which has 11 consecutive bits set to 1. This
   used to be 12, but it was tweaked to allow for MPEG version 2.5.
3. Determine the MPEG version ID. For the purposes of finding the bit rate, V2.5 is the same as V2
4. Determine the layer description
5. Read the bit rate index
6. Using the MPEG version, layer description and bit rate index, determine the actual bit rate from the bit rate index table in the linked header reference
7. Divide the file size in kilobits ((8 * size in bytes) / 1000) by the bit rate to get the duration in seconds

I couldn't find a Delphi sample, but here is a [C# implementation](https://web.archive.org/web/20011221185412/http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=79) that uses this technique for reference purposes. See the getLengthInSeconds method.

Comment: +1, the code for computing the length in seconds is identical to what I found.

Comment: Downvoted: link-only answer where the linked article has disappeared since written.

Comment: @Jules: I appreciate a reason for the down vote, which was valid. I fixed the link and added a summary of the steps required and a link to the header reference.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to use BASS

http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html

*BASS is an audio library .. to provide developers with powerful stream (MP3.. OGG.. ) functions. All in a tiny DLL, under 100KB in size.*

it's very easy to use

```
   uses BASS;

   var
      playingChannel: HSTREAM;
      playingLength: Double;
      mp3filename: String;

    begin
      BASS_Init(-1,44100,0,Application.Handle,nil);
      playingChannel:=BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE,pchar(mp3filename),0,0,0);
      playingLength:=BASS_ChannelBytes2Seconds(playingChannel,
        BASS_ChannelGetLength(playingChannel,BASS_POS_BYTE));
    end;
```

Comment: Is not free though, is it?

Comment: it is, for non commercial use. See "licensing" on www.un4seen.com

Answer (score 3):

[Mp3 are divided into frames like this](http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html)

You will need to count the number of frames

Comment: is not as simple as saying. The mp3 file have a lot of information before the frames start...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this will work, but I found this [forum post](http://lists.runrev.com/pipermail/metacard/2003-August/005760.html).  I'd compare results with something like winamp to make sure it works.

Comment: Accurate for CBR (constant bitrate), likely inaccurate for VBR (variable bitrate).  In cases where only an approximate time is needed, this is a good idea

Comment: Although this method assumes you know the bitrate!

Comment: @Charlie Salts - Your'e correct, the formula won't work in VBR cases, and the forum post has no indication of how to determine the bitrate.  Bruce McGee's answer is more complete, and I'd recommend that one over mine.

Answer (score 2):

Under windows there is a reasonably effective way of determining the length of an MP3 file.

This is a huge hack but it seems to work.

Ryan.

```
//add MPlayer to the uses clause;
//
//add the MP3PlayLength function to an existing form and 
//place a button on the form, linking the button click method to see how it works.

uses MPlayer;

function TForm1.MP3PlayLength(aMP3FileName:string):string;
var
  wMP : TMediaPlayer;
  wLen : Cardinal;
begin
  Try
     wMP := TMediaPlayer.Create(self);
     try
        wMP.Visible := false;
        wMP.parent := self;
        wMP.FileName := aMP3FileName;
        wMP.TimeFormat := tfMilliseconds;
        wMP.DeviceType := dtAutoSelect;
        wMP.Open;
        try
           wLen := trunc(wMP.Length / 1000);
           result := inttostr(wLen div 60)+':'+inttostr(wLen mod 60);
        finally
           wMP.Close;
        end;
     finally
        wMP.free;
     end;
  except
     result := '(err)';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if OpenDialog1.Execute then
      showmessage(MP3PlayLength(OpenDialog1.FileName));
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, try MediaInfo.dll [link text](http://mediainfo.sf.net).

It's included a Delphi wrapper class.
For example:

```
MediaInfo_Get(Handle, Stream_General, 0, 'Duration', Info_Text, Info_Name)
```

Other solution DSPack [link text](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=4)

```
size := FilterGraph.Duration;
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to www.un4seen.com and download bass library you will get a lot of info from the forum section. ;)

Answer (score 0):

checkout this blog, using ffmpeg for background workaround in a ruby project.

http://blog.ncodedev.com

Answer (score -1):

It's been a long time since I played with Dephi.

Try,

```
FileSize(var aFile)
```

Comment: That will give the size in bytes, not minutes and seconds.

Comment: @Charlie Salts - This was posted before OP explained that they wanted minutes/seconds. I'd give Secko a break. Also, FileSize() might be helpful and used in the formula Bruce and I posted about.

Comment: The question was "How do you get the length of an MP3/wav audio file in Delphi?".

Comment: I would have assumed the poster meant length in time.  If they had asked for the length of *any* file, I would have assumed file size.  Getting the file size of any file is usually trivial, getting length of an MP3 sometimes is not trivial, hence the question.

Comment: I agree, but my brain somehow just sent me a picture of the FileSize function.