# Read out Time/Length/Duration of an Mp3 song in Java

Tags: java, audio, mp3

I wonder how I can read out the duration of an mp3 song. If I'm right it's not an ID3 Tag so I guess I have to calculate it somehow ?
For the rest of the ID3 Tags I'm using this libary:
http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/index.html

Cheers

Comment: Oh yeah I'm using JLayer for playing the mp3 if that matters somehow

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a mp3 file's total time in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046669/how-do-i-get-a-mp3-files-total-time-in-java)

Comment: Try using `jave-1.0.1.jar` library: [How do I get a mp3 file's total time in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046669)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the code to...

```
File file = new File("filename.mp3");
AudioFileFormat baseFileFormat = new MpegAudioFileReader().getAudioFileFormat(file);
Map properties = baseFileFormat.properties();
Long duration = (Long) properties.get("duration");
```

using [MP3SPI](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html) to use `new MpegAudioFileReader()` instead of `AudioSystem`, because i was getting an `UnsupportedAudioFileException occured : file is not a supported file type` with mp3 files

Comment: This method is not working for this track: https://www.dropbox.com/s/735fdkp9roskapw/39007.mp3?dl=0 - The track has 3:52, but this code sais it has 22:17.

Comment: Currently the hashmap returned by .properties() doesn't even have a key called "duration", at least not that I can find.

Comment: @php_coder_3809625 - right.  Here's the keys of the properties map for an MP3 I just tried it on.  No "duration", nor is there anything that you could reasonably calculate one from: `mp3.copyright, date, mp3.framesize.bytes, mp3.vbr, mp3.framerate.fps, mp3.id3tag.track, title, mp3.channels, mp3.id3tag.genre, mp3.bitrate.nominal.bps, mp3.padding, mp3.version.mpeg, mp3.crc, mp3.original, mp3.frequency.hz, album, author, mp3.id3tag.v2, mp3.vbr.scale, mp3.version.encoding, mp3.version.layer, mp3.id3tag.v2.version, mp3.header.pos, comment`

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [MP3SPI](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html) which is based on JLayer. The following code will then allow you to get the song duration:

```
File file = new File("filename.mp3");
AudioFileFormat baseFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
Map properties = baseFileFormat.properties();
Long duration = (Long) properties.get("duration");
```

You can also use MP3SPI to get at the ID3 tags which might save you an extra dependency.

Comment: This method is not working for this track: https://www.dropbox.com/s/735fdkp9roskapw/39007.mp3?dl=0 - The track has 3:52, but this code sais it has 22:17.

Answer (score 0):

Use some MP3 library. The MP3 format is not that easy that there is some simple way to read out the length of a song.